# Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' in Spring

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot

I've been trying to configure and create a simple schema using ***application.yaml*** file:

```
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      continue-on-error: false
      data-locations: classpath:sql/demo-data.sql
```

and ***schema.sql***, ***demo_data.sql*** files. I wrote SQL scripts for creating some tables and inserting to them demo data:

** File schema.sql**

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tasklist;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    expiration_date TIMESTAMP NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_tasks
(
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    task_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, task_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_tasks_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_tasks_tasks FOREIGN KEY (task_id) REFERENCES tasks (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_roles
(
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_roles_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

File demo_data.sql

```
INSERT INTO users (name, username, password)
VALUES ('John Doe', 'johndoe@gmail.com', '$2a$10$Xl0yhvzLIaJCDdKBS0Lld.ksK7c2Zytg/ZKFdtIYYQUv8rUfvCR4W'),
       ('Mike Smith', 'mikesmith@yahoo.com', '$2a$10$fFLij9aYgaNCFPTL9WcA/uoCRukxnwf.vOQ8nrEEOskrCNmGsxY7m');

INSERT INTO tasks (title, description, status, expiration_date)
VALUES ('Buy cheese', null, 'TODO', '2023-01-29 12:00:00'),
       ('Do homework', 'Math, Physics, Literature', 'IN_PROGRESS', '2023-01-31 00:00:00'),
       ('Clean rooms', null, 'DONE', null),
       ('Call Mike', 'Ask about meeting', 'TODO', '2023-02-01 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO users_tasks (task_id, user_id)
VALUES (1, 2),
       (2, 2),
       (3, 2),
       (4, 1);

INSERT INTO users_roles (user_id, role)
VALUES (1, 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
       (1, 'ROLE_USER'),
       (2, 'ROLE_USER');
```

But when I start my Spring Boot application, tables are created properly when *data inserting* fails with next exception: **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException** Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource. ***Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [sql/demo_data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (name, username, password) VALUES ('John Doe', 'johndoe@gmail.com', '$2a$10$Xl0yhvzLIaJCDdKBS0Lld.ksK7c2Zytg/ZKFdtIYYQUv8rUfvCR4W'), ('Mike Smith', 'mikesmith@yahoo.com', '$2a$10$fFLij9aYgaNCFPTL9WcA/uoCRukxnwf.vOQ8nrEEOskrCNmGsxY7m')*** even though sql script runs correctly if I do it using console.

How is it possible to fix that the data from *demo_data.sql* file inserts into my tables when I start my Spring Boot application?